# Discord.js awaitmessage error, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was making this new bot and used awaitmessage function.When a user use the cmd '!gangsug', the bot is supposed to ask a question like - "Please choose a option - RP or Fight" and when the user uses an option it is supposed to give a reply. (Which is a embed one). I have given two different replies for the 2 answers given by the user.(One for the answer "RP" and the other for the answer "Fight"). In this case, by bot is giving same answer for both answer. If the user types "RP" or "Fight" same reply is being given
by the bot. I hope you understood the problem.The code will be given below (ofc only the part where the problem comes)

```
if (message.content === `${prefix}gangsug`) {

                  message.reply('Hey there! Please choose a option.\n'
                          + 'Confirm with `RP` or with `Fight`.');

                  // First argument is a filter function - which is made of conditions
                  // m is a 'Message' object
                  message.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id == message.author.id,
                          {max: 1, time: 30000}).then(collected => {
                                  // only accept messages by the user who sent the command
                                  // accept only 1 message, and return the promise after 30000ms = 30s

                                  // first (and, in this case, only) message of the collection
                                 if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() == 'RP') {
                                          message.reply(suggestgang1);
                            
                                  }

                                  else
                                          message.reply(suggestgang2);
                                          message.reply(suggestgang3);    
                                        
                          }).catch(() => {
                                  message.reply('No answer after 30 seconds, req canceled.');
                          });
                  
       }       }  
  
);
```

**Yea, this is the code..It would be great of you give an answer by stating the problem and a fixed code to replace this one. Thank you :) **

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in this line:

```js
if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() == 'RP')
```

---

Since you used the `.toLowerCase()` method on the message content, it's physically impossible to match anything uppercase, such as 'RP'.

```js
if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() == 'rp')
```

Comment: oh, damn! I never tought in that way, thank you..let me try it